# merge particular column value in sql 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need an SQL query to merge two rows.
I've created a view ,the output is like this:

```
PDesc       PrjCode PCode   A_No    A_Qty   B_No    B_Qty   C_No   C_Qty
KPPPPPPP    14-0123 6519    1090    58      NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL
Head SS ST4 14-0123 4322    1090    354960  741     354960  592    350000
Head SS ST4 14-0123 4322    1090    354960  741     354960  771    4960
XXXXXXX     14-0123 5668    1090    408     741     408     592   408
```

I need the rows with same qyt to be merged ,but the other columns should be shown in seperate rows:
Here the if the A_No is same then only one  A_Qty should display and if B_No is repeating one B_Qty is enough ,so it should not get repeated ,

```
PDesc       PrjCode PCode   A_No    A_Qty   B_No    B_Qty   C_No   C_Qty
KPPPPPPP    14-0123 6519    1090    58      NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL
Head SS ST4 14-0123 4322    1090    354960  741     354960  592    350000
Head SS ST4 14-0123 4322    1090            741             771    4960
XXXXXXX     14-0123 5668    1090    408     741     408     592   408
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How you know the `A_Qty` and the `B_Qty` are emptied in the second row? How are you sorting the rows? In ascending way using `C_No` column or in a descending way using the `C_Qty` column?

Comment: Depending on how this merge is being performed, one easy option might be to use `DISTINCT` on the first table _before_ joining it to the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function to access a previous row value. Then simply, if the previous row value is the same as the current row value, return `NULL`- if not, return the current row value.Of course, you need to order the rows in a particular way.

For example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [PDesc] VARCHAR(16)
   ,[PrjCode] CHAR(7)
   ,[PCode] CHAR(4)
   ,[A_No]  CHAR(4)
   ,[A_Qty] INT
   ,[B_No] INT
   ,[B_Qty] INT
   ,[C_No] INT 
   ,[C_Qty] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([PDesc], [PrjCode], [PCode], [A_No], [A_Qty], [B_No], [B_Qty], [C_No], [C_Qty])
VALUES ('KPPPPPPP', '14-0123', '6519', '1090', '58', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
      ,('Head SS ST4', '14-0123', '4322', '1090', '354960', '741', '354960', '592', '350000')
      ,('Head SS ST4', '14-0123', '4322', '1090', '354960', '741', '354960', '771', '4960')
      ,('XXXXXXX', '14-0123', '5668', '1090', '408', '741', '408', '592', '408');

SELECT [PDesc]
      ,[PrjCode]
      ,[PCode]
      ,[A_No]
      ,IIF(LAG([A_Qty], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [PDesc], [PrjCode] ORDER BY [C_No]) = [A_Qty], NULL, [A_Qty]) AS [A_Qty]
      ,[B_No]
      ,IIF(LAG([B_Qty], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [PDesc], [PrjCode] ORDER BY [B_Qty]) = [B_Qty], NULL, [B_Qty]) AS [B_Qty]
      ,[C_No]
      ,[C_Qty]
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

---

So, what is the following expression doing:

```
LAG([A_Qty], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [PDesc], [PrjCode] ORDER BY [C_No])
```

- `LAG([A_Qty], 1, NULL)` means give me the previous row value of the
  `[A_Qty]` column
- `PARTITION BY [PDesc], [PrjCode]` means we are ordering rows only where the `[PDesc], [PrjCode]` pair values are the same. You cam skip this if you do not need it.
- `ORDER BY [C_No]` defines how rows are ordered in a given partition (this is how you define which row is previous to another)